# Creating programming language question

Tags: objective-c, c, compiler-theory

I'm thinking about creating a custom (small) programming language (syntax) based on C.
I don't understand how apple implemented objective-c with operators like [testClass runThis:true]; with that syntax.

How would i implement a custom syntax for my custom c language

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You might want to look at [Clang](http://clang.llvm.org/) (the C, C++ and Obj-C frontend of the LLVM compiler) and the [Eero Programming Language](http://eerolanguage.org/), a new language based on Objective-C that was built with LLVM. Both projects are open-source.

Answer (score 2):

You'd need to implement a parser and a lexer to start with. One way to go about it is to get the C syntax and grammar from K&R's "The C programming language" and use that as input to Flex and Bison to create a standalone parser. That will parse syntactically valid C programs. After that, you can tweak it as you want and customise it.

This is however a non trivial project and you'll have to be prepared to teach yourself a lot about compilers. Good luck!

Comment: I'm trying to create my custom syntaxed programming language based on C, like objective-c

Answer (score 1):

The bit inside `[...]` is based on the syntax of [Smalltalk](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Smalltalk).

As for designing your own language, that is quite a big subject.  You need to acquaint yourself with [context free grammars](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Context-free_grammar), [lexical analysis](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lexical_analysis), [recursive descent parsers](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Recursive_descent_parser), [LALR parsers](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/LALR_parser), and we haven't even got to the problem of generating executable code yet.  Still it's all good fun.  Designing and implementing workable computer languages is a challenging but (IMO) rewarding exercise.

Answer (score 1):

You'll have to write a compiler.  If your semantics fit, you might be able to compile directly to C code; otherwise you'll have to also write some kind of runtime for the bits of your language which don't easily and directly translate to C.  Given that you're talking about a small C-based language, though, that's probably not an issue.

How do you go about doing this?  Oh.  Man.

There are dozens of books, articles, tutorials, etc. on the subject of [writing a compiler](http://www.google.com/search?sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8&q=writing+a+compiler).  While no individual piece of a compiler is particularly difficult (at least for naive, non-optimizing compilers), there is a whole lot of stuff to contend with in a whole lot of different ways, often ways which are subtly incompatible with each other.

At the very least you'll want a [lexer](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lexical_analysis) (usually through an automated tool like [flex](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flex_lexical_analyser) or as part of a compiler suite like [ANTLR](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ANTLR)), a [parser](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parsing) (usually through automated tools like [Bison](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GNU_Bison) and the aforementioned ANTLR) and a [code generator](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code_generation_%28compiler%29) (usually generated by hand).  In reality you'll probably want to stick an [abstract syntax tree](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abstract_syntax_tree) between the parser and the code generator to give you (or someone else) room for implementing various [optimizations](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Compiler_optimization) and for making code generation simpler.

There are [lots of books](http://www.google.com/search?sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8&q=compiler+design+book) available on this topic, not to mention research papers.  Have fun.  What you're trying to do is challenging but rewarding when you pull it off.

Answer (score 0):

Step up to C++ and you have the possibility to create a DSEL (Domain-Specific Embedded Language).  I don't know what problem you're trying to solve but a well designed DSEL might be much more convenient than designing your own language and creating parsers, compilers, etc.  Grab a copy of this book for some insight: [C++ Template Metaprogramming](http://www.boostpro.com/mplbook/)